# Create a file for writing with controlled flushing to disk in large chunks

Tags: linux, files, ffmpeg, buffer

On Linux I have a process (ffmpeg) that writes very slowly (even slower than 1kb / s sometimes) to disk. Ffmpeg can buffer this to 256kb chunks that get written infrequently but ffmpeg hangs occasionally and if I try to detect these hangs by checking that the file is being updated I need to wait a long time between updates, up to 10 or 15 mins, otherwise I can sometimes mistakenly kill the ffmpeg process when it appears to have stopped writing when it fact its still filling its internal buffer.

Theres no way to detect this it seems unless I use strace (that I can find anyway). So I am wondering about turning off buffering in ffmpeg and writing unbuffered to disk from ffmpeg.

This will result in the disk constantly making tiny writes and wasting power (and probably, if I use a SSD, mess with wear levelling too).

So I would like to make ffmpeg write to a 'virtual file' (in memory - either kernel memory or a process) which I can specify the flushing characteristics of. The idea being to perhaps specify flush every 2 minutes, then I can keep an eye on the file size and make sure its still being written.

I don't think I've missed any other ways to do this job - even if I could watch the socket stream incoming to ffpmeg the process itself could still stop writing and lose data. Doing the buffering outside of ffmpeg seems like the best way.

Is there a built in way to do this in Linux or does it mean a custom process? I guess I know how to do this with a small C program and pipe the data in but I wonder if theres a neater way.

Comment: Your method of detecting hangups seems to me to be inappropriate. If the write rates are so low, then watching the output done size is just not the right approach, and no amount of making buffering work worse can fix that, I'm afraid.

Comment: OK thanks, appreciate your thoughts on this - what is the right way to do it in your opinion? Meuh below has suggested a way to achieve what I was originally asking which looks good to me but it would still be interesting to get more detail re your comment if you could.

Comment: Well your ffmpeg hangs. Figure out what it's doing when it hangs - debug it. You can then either use the same debugging methodology to figure out whether you're stuck, or, much better, actually fix the problem

Comment: I agree in an ideal world but in this case its probably not the ffmpeg thats the problem, the stream is provided by a Chinese DVR. The rtsp stream seems to stop randomly from time to time, and takes a minute or two to restart. What exactly happens I am not sure, admittedly, when watching via ffplay the image freezes and stays like that - ffplay does not stop or signal an error. Ffmpeg recording does seem to stop writing to disk. Perhaps I could modify ffmpeg to detect the loss of whatever it is that stops but it would require heavy work to figure out whats going on and I don't have the time.

Comment: Perhaps ideally I (or someone) would update ffmpeg to gracefully handle this situation but I don't know that there is much appetite for such a mod, I don't see many people complaining of this problem. It seems like too much to expect to get the devs to fix it, especially if there is an effective workaround (which I am hoping the file size watching will be). Remembering too that most likely the DVR is at fault, bloating ffmpeg to cater for an obscure failure of a badly made video source also has its downsides.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess, it'd be that the stream just stops supplying packets. Wonder whether you could just monitor the packet count?

Comment: Funny you mention that! I tried to figure out how to do this via proc and failed :-( Investigations around the web also didn't reveal how to do it. I hypothesised that somewhere in the proc dir for this process there would be a counter for RX data or packets, but I couldn't find it. If you know of a way to do this that would be great. Essentially what I am looking for (I think) is just RX stats for a particular socket (obviously not the whole interface - just this particular socket owned by this process). Should be in proc surely? Or elsewhere? Nice clean way to do this if its possible IMO.

Comment: nope, not really, but you can monitor traffic using e.g. netfilter/eBPF or preloads that log `reads` on a socket

Comment: (also wonder whether ffmpeg has some timeout options to simply give up after a fixed amount of time with no packet data)

Comment: Timeout would be good - just does not seem to be there for rtsp though unless its an undocumented feature. Can't find anyone mentioning it on google but I might check the source to see if anything is there. Re the netfilter can you go into a bit more detail? I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GNU `dd` for this; it was designed to reblock data when reading/writing tape drives optimally. Pipe the unbuffered output into, for example,

```
dd obs=20k status=progress >/the/file
```

where `20k` is the output block size you wish to use for each write to disk. `k` means kibibytes. With `status=progress` you get a line on stderr which updates when a write is done, e.g.

```
20480 bytes (20 kB, 20 KiB) copied, 12 s, 1.7 kB/s
```

If you prefer, omit this option and kill `dd` with signal SIGUSR1 when you want it to write out the progress.